# Optimization for drawing same bitmap many times on android?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I have roads that I draw using tiling:

```
    float sizeW;
    float sizeH;
    if(isTopBottom())
    {
        sizeW = getWidth();
        sizeH = (sizeW / image.getWidth()) * image.getHeight();
    }
    else
    {
        sizeW = getHeight();
        sizeH = (sizeW / image.getWidth()) * image.getHeight();

    }

    int numTiles = isTopBottom() ? (int)Math.ceil(getHeight() / sizeH) :
        (int)Math.ceil(getWidth() / sizeW);

    for(int i = 0; i < numTiles; ++i)
    {
        if(isTopBottom())
        {
            c.drawRotatedScaledBitmap(
                    image,
                    getRect().left + (sizeW / 2.0f),
                    (getRect().top + (sizeH / 2.0f)) + (sizeH * i), 
                    sizeW, sizeH, 0.0f);
        }
        else
        {
            c.drawRotatedScaledBitmap(
                    image,
                    getRect().left + (sizeH / 2.0f) + (sizeH * i),
                    getRect().top + (sizeH / 2.0f), 
                    sizeW, sizeH, (float)Math.PI / 2.0f);
        }

    }
```

I know OpenGL hates texture bindings. Is android smart enough to avoid these texture binds or is there a way I can explicitly tell it I'm drawing the same bitmap over and over?

Thanks

Comment: "*I know OpenGL hates texture bindings.*" How do you know that? The cost of binding a texture is implementation specific. Furthermore, if you "know" this, why aren't you taking steps in your `drawRotatedScaledBitmap` code to not bind the same texture more than once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenGL is a state machine, so once you make a bind() call, there is no need to make another in order to draw the same texture.